# Android : Having trouble using visibility on xml layout file

Tags: android, exception, layout, visibility

I having a trouble using visibility in one of my controls.

I can set the control in the xml file saying  and it work ok. but if i have a string.xml with value of visibility = gone and pass that value to the button tag in the layout file eg   . It will force close due to this exception.

```
10-01 01:23:42.950: E/AndroidRuntime(914): Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "gone"
10-01 01:23:42.950: E/AndroidRuntime(914):  at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
10-01 01:23:42.950: E/AndroidRuntime(914):  at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:375)
10-01 01:23:42.950: E/AndroidRuntime(914):  at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:366)
10-01 01:23:42.950: E/AndroidRuntime(914):  at com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils.convertValueToInt(XmlUtils.java:123)
10-01 01:23:42.950: E/AndroidRuntime(914):  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getInt(TypedArray.java:254)
10-01 01:23:42.950: E/AndroidRuntime(914):  at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3451)
10-01 01:23:42.950: E/AndroidRuntime(914):  at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:447)
10-01 01:23:42.950: E/AndroidRuntime(914):  at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:442)
```

Comment: Please post your layout? Why are you trying to use string.xml this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [View | Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3avisibility), the visibility actually accepts `int` value, not `String`. The value `gone` in XML is a constant mapped to the integer, not a String. The solution is to type `android:visibility="gone"` directly without using string resource.

Answer (score 1):

GONE is an integer constant (it's value is actually 2, as listed in [the documentation for the View class here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3avisibility)). It is not processed as a string.

Answer (score 1):

As you know View has 3 kind of properties and all these reference mapped into an integer value.
As given below.

1. visible  -0
2. invisible-1
3. gone     -2

This is not a string. that's the reason you are facing this problem.

**To solve this problem you can use integer from xml or programmatically you can use 
`view.setVisibility(View.GONE);`**

Hope this will help you..